# Proving that a BST with N>=1 nodes will have log(N+1) levels

Tags: graphs, data-structures, binary-trees, induction

I am trying to prove by induction  the following theorem:
Use Induction to prove the following fact: for every integer, $N\ge  1$ , a BST with $N$ nodes must have at least $\log( N + 1)$ levels.
I've proved the base case but I am struggling to figure out how to apply induction to prove for the $K+1$ case. Any suggestions would be wonderful.

Comment: try to prove that any binary tree with $2^k$ nodes must have $k+1$ levels, it is better to avoid log.

Comment: and remember that a binary tree= 1 root+ 2 binary trees

Comment: Wonder if there is already a duplicate of this.

Comment: Raphael's answer of [Proving a binary tree has at most $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ leaves](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/805/proving-a-binary-tree-has-at-most-lceil-n-2-rceil-leaves) should help for this question as well.