# Prove any binary tree with $n$ nodes has at least $1+\log_2 n$ levels

Tags: graphs, binary-trees

Prove that any binary tree with $n$ nodes has at least $1+\log_2 n$ levels.
I tried setting $n=8$ and plugging in $8\geq\log_2 8 = 8\geq 3$. But I'm not sure how I can prove this by induction.

Comment: How does showing that $8\geq 3$ establish anything about binary trees? You need to relate the number of leaves and numebr of levels, not $n$ and $\log n$.

Comment: What does the shallowest binary tree on $n$ nodes look like? There will be 1 node at the root (level 0), 2 child nodes at level 1, 4 at level 2 so for $n = 7 (=1+2+4)$ there must be at least 2 levels. Generalize this.

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/805/proving-a-binary-tree-has-at-most-lceil-n-2-rceil-leaves?rq=1).

Comment: The induction is elementary; do you [understand induction in principle](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4905/how-do-i-write-a-proof-using-induction-on-the-length-of-the-input-string)? What has to be the anchor here? Over which quantity should we do the induction?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A binary tree with $1+h$ levels contains at most $1+2+2^2+\cdots+2^h = 2^{h+1}-1$ vertices.